# Upgrading to python 3.x on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, miniconda

I have Ubuntu 18.04. I want to upgrade to python 3.x

When I do:

```
python --version
```

I get:

```
Python 2.7.17
```

But then I run:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

it says:

```
python3 is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
```

I guess this means that I have more than one version of python on my laptop? What's the best way for me to clean this up? Should I delete one? I made a bit of a mess installing / uninstalling anaconda / miniconda at various points in my life, and so that has probably not helped.

I just want to have a clean install of python 3, and then I will reinstall miniconda after.

Comment: `python` is python 2.x. `python3` is python 3.x. See [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/)

Comment: i wouldn't remove Python 2 because system may still use it to run some functions. Better use `python3` or `python3.6`. The same with `pip`, `pip2`, `pip3`, `pip3.6`.

Comment: BTW: I use Linux Mint based on Ubuntu 18.04 and at this moment I have command `python`, `python2`, `python2.7`, `python3`, `python3.6, `python3.7`, `python3.8`, `python3.9` and the same with `pip`, `pip2`, `pup2.7`, `pip3`, `pip3.6`, `pip3.7`, `pip3.8`, `pip3.9` and I can use different versions. Sometimes there is no module for newest version and I still use 3.7 as main version.

Comment: BTW: unofficial repository for Ubuntu with Pythons 2.3 ... 3.9: https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: I guess my question is - how do I have python3 execute any python script I run and not python 2.7.17?

Comment: in every script I add shebang `#!/usr/bin/python3.7` in first line and set script  executable `chmod a+x script.py` and then I can run it as any other program - `$ script.py` instead of `$ python script.py`. I could even remove extension or use extension ie. `.jpg` and Linux still will run it with Python 3.7

Comment: _I just want to have a clean install of python 3, and then I will reinstall miniconda after._ Why do you want a new install of Python 3 **and** miniconda? Have you not suffered enough already? ;)

Comment: @furas _BTW: I use Linux Mint based on Ubuntu 18.04 and at this moment I have command python, python2, python2.7, python3, python3.6, python3.7, python3.8, python3.9` and the same with pip, pip2, pup2.7, pip3, pip3.6, pip3.7, pip3.8, pip3.9 and I can use different versions._ That's brutal, are you not using virtual environments or anything like that?

Comment: @AMC every version uses own folder with modules - so different versions can live together without conflicts. For most code I use only 3.7 and it needs `venv` (and `git`) to make projects safe - ie to run always with the same version of `Django`. But for small scripts which I use many times every day to resolve small problems I don't use `venv` - they mostly use standard modules which don't changes. The same with code created only to answers - they don't need `venv`. it is used only once. Other Python versions I use only to see new functions or test problems from SO.

Comment: @AMC I just thought that I needed python 3 so that I could install miniconda. Obviously I don't really understand how it all works. I basically just want to get Jupyter Notebooks working. It seemed like getting miniconda installed properly was the way to go. To do that I thought I needed the latest python.

Comment: @user1551817 It doesn't look like you need to have Python installed, take a look [here](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).

Answer (score 3):

To run Python 3 instead of Python 2 type:

```
python3
```

If you want Python 3 to run by default you can add the following to the aliases section of your .bashrc:

```
# some more ls aliases
alias python='python3'
```

To update Python3:

```
sudo apt upgrade python3
```